# Calculating median of a column sequentially in R and storing values in dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, csv, median

I am facing an issue to compute the median of values in a column.
I have hundreds of values in a column but I want to compute the median of five values in a sequence at a time and store the median value in a separate data frame in R and similarly continue until the end of data values available.

The issue is there are some values with **#VALUE!** and while computing the median if there comes such a value i.e. **#VALUE!** and there are less than 5 values to take median, then the program should just take the median with whatever number of values are available.
Similarly, for the last median value, if there are less than 5 values available to take a median, then it should compute the median with the available number of values.

The link to the .csv file with one column of sample data could be downloaded from here.

[LINK to FILE](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ntkh7KD8MSzG--RzfLEQhHGoyxIAH9O2/view?usp=sharing)

If someone can help me with this I would be very grateful.

Thank you

Comment: The presence of your `#VALUE!` error is not an R thing, I believe that's an Excel-only thing. If you are seeing that, are you using some R/Excel integration? Regardless, "five values in a sequence" sounds like a rolling calculation, easily done using `zoo::rollmedian` (generically `zoo::rollapply`) or one of the `slider`-package equivalent functions (I'm not as familiar). Side note: many people prefer to not click on external links, *and links go stale*, it's helpful to have sample data in the question itself. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

1. Group by a sequence of 5 rows
2. replace `#VALUE!` with `NA`
3. convert to numeric
4. summarise with median

```
Speed %>% 
  group_by(group5 = rep(row_number(), each=5, length.out = n())) %>% 
  mutate(speed = ifelse(speed== "#VALUE!", NA, speed)) %>% 
  type.convert(as.is = TRUE) %>% 
  summarise(median = median(speed, na.rm = TRUE))
```

```
  group5 median
    <int>  <dbl>
 1      1   1.32
 2      2  -4.97
 3      3 -13.1 
 4      4 -14.3 
 5      5   6.89
 6      6  -2.97
 7      7 -11.6 
 8      8 -16.0 
 9      9 -18.6 
10     10 -19.9 
# ... with 72 more rows
```

Comment: Thanks for this. 
The output is exactly what I want but when I try to run the code it gives me the following error:

Error in group_by(., group = rep(row_number(), each = 5, length.out = n())) : 
  object 'Speed' not found

How can correct it?

Comment: TarJae named the variable `Speed` in their console. What do you name it in your console?

Comment: `Speed` is the name of the dataframe. `speed` is the name of the column!

Comment: Ahh got it. Sorry I made a silly mistake. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

**Update** for "tumbling window" (top, here) versus "rolling window" (below, kept for posterity/reference). Still using the `dat` from the top of the rolling-window discussion.

The discussion about `#VALUE!` (far below) may still be relevant, I'll include the code here.

### base R

```r
dat$speed <- suppressWarnings(as.numeric(dat$speed))
aggregate(dat$speed, list(grp = (seq_len(nrow(dat)) - 1) %/% 5), FUN = median, na.rm = TRUE)
#   grp       x
# 1   0  3.4245
# 2   1 -4.9730
```

### dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  mutate(speed = suppressWarnings(as.numeric(speed))) %>%
  group_by(grp = (seq_len(n()) - 1) %/% 5) %>%
  summarize(med5 = median(speed, na.rm = TRUE))
# # A tibble: 2 x 2
#     grp  med5
#   <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     0  3.42
# 2     1 -4.97
```

### data.table

```r
library(data.table)
as.data.table(dat)[, speed := suppressWarnings(as.numeric(speed))
  ][, .(med5 = median(speed, na.rm = TRUE)), by = .(grp = (seq_len(nrow(dat)) - 1) %/% 5)][]
#      grp    med5
#    <num>   <num>
# 1:     0  3.4245
# 2:     1 -4.9730
```

---

(This below is for rolling-windows, no longer relevant other than the definition of `dat` data.)

---

I copied the first 10 rows from that single-column frame, and get

```r
dat <- structure(list(speed = c(0, 5.534, 1.315, 7.6865, -0.479, -0.4605, -4.311, -4.973, -7.69, -11.669)), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"), class = "data.frame")
```

With this, the basic operation is something like this:

```r
newvec <- zoo::rollmedian(dat$speed, 5)
newvec
# [1]  1.3150  1.3150 -0.4605 -0.4790 -4.3110 -4.9730
```

Note that this creates `nrow(dat) - (k - 1)` (20) values, where `k=5` (your window). In general, rolling operations tend to be reductive, but we have options to change that if needed. For instance, we can keep it the same length and pad the ends with `NA`; to do this, we can "align" the window left, center, or right:

```r
zoo::rollmedian(dat$speed, 5, fill = NA, align = "left")
#  [1]  1.3150  1.3150 -0.4605 -0.4790 -4.3110 -4.9730      NA      NA      NA      NA
zoo::rollmedian(dat$speed, 5, fill = NA, align = "center")
#  [1]      NA      NA  1.3150  1.3150 -0.4605 -0.4790 -4.3110 -4.9730      NA      NA
zoo::rollmedian(dat$speed, 5, fill = NA, align = "right")
#  [1]      NA      NA      NA      NA  1.3150  1.3150 -0.4605 -0.4790 -4.3110 -4.9730
```

Let me show how alignment fits here. With `align="center"` (the default), we see:

```r
dat$speed
#  [1]   0.0000   5.5340   1.3150   7.6865  -0.4790  -0.4605  -4.3110  -4.9730  -7.6900 -11.6690
###      `----------------------------------------'
###          take the median of these values,
###          and then assign that single value here:
###                                              /
###                             ,---------------'
###                            / 
#  [1]       NA       NA   1.3150   1.3150  -0.4605  -0.4790  -4.3110  -4.9730       NA       NA

dat$speed[1:5]
# [1]  0.0000  5.5340  1.3150  7.6865 -0.4790
median(dat$speed[1:5])
# [1] 1.315
```

For the next value,

```r
#  [1]   0.0000   5.5340   1.3150   7.6865  -0.4790  -0.4605  -4.3110  -4.9730  -7.6900 -11.6690
###               `----------------------------------------'
###                   take the median of these values,
###                   and then assign that single value here:
###                                                       /
###                                      ,---------------'
###                                     / 
#  [1]       NA       NA   1.3150   1.3150  -0.4605  -0.4790  -4.3110  -4.9730       NA       NA

dat$speed[2:6]
# [1]  5.5340  1.3150  7.6865 -0.4790 -0.4605
median(dat$speed[2:6])
# [1] 1.315
```

So we can assign that easily to a new frame with `data.frame(rollmed = newvec)`, with or without padding. If you want to assign it back to the original frame, one can do:

```r
dat$rollmed <- zoo::rollmedian(dat$speed, 5, fill = NA, align = "center")
dat
#       speed rollmed
# 1    0.0000      NA
# 2    5.5340      NA
# 3    1.3150  1.3150
# 4    7.6865  1.3150
# 5   -0.4790 -0.4605
# 6   -0.4605 -0.4790
# 7   -4.3110 -4.3110
# 8   -4.9730 -4.9730
# 9   -7.6900      NA
# 10 -11.6690      NA
```

---

As for your `#VALUE!`, that likely manifests as a `character` column instead of `numeric`, in which case you have an extra step *before* all of the above.

I'll change one of my values to that error:

```r
dat$speed[5] <- "#VALUE!"
dat
#      speed
# 1        0
# 2    5.534
# 3    1.315
# 4   7.6865
# 5  #VALUE!
# 6  -0.4605
# 7   -4.311
# 8   -4.973
# 9    -7.69
# 10 -11.669
str(dat)
# 'data.frame': 10 obs. of  1 variable:
#  $ speed: chr  "0" "5.534" "1.315" "7.6865" ...
```

(See? `chr`.)

From here, we can simply convert all to numbers, ignoring the warnings we get:

```r
dat$speed <- suppressWarnings(as.numeric(dat$speed))
dat
#       speed
# 1    0.0000
# 2    5.5340
# 3    1.3150
# 4    7.6865
# 5        NA
# 6   -0.4605
# 7   -4.3110
# 8   -4.9730
# 9   -7.6900
# 10 -11.6690
str(dat)
# 'data.frame': 10 obs. of  1 variable:
#  $ speed: num  0 5.53 1.31 7.69 NA ...
```

And from here, we can do the rolling median again. Note that the `NA` we now have changes things slightly:

```r
dat$rollmed <- zoo::rollmedian(dat$speed, 5, fill = NA, align = "center")
dat$rollmed2 <- zoo::rollmedian(dat$speed, 5, fill = NA, align = "center", na.rm = TRUE)
dat
#       speed rollmed rollmed2
# 1    0.0000      NA       NA
# 2    5.5340      NA       NA
# 3    1.3150      NA  3.42450
# 4    7.6865      NA  3.42450
# 5        NA      NA  0.42725
# 6   -0.4605      NA -2.38575
# 7   -4.3110      NA -4.64200
# 8   -4.9730  -4.973 -4.97300
# 9   -7.6900      NA       NA
# 10 -11.6690      NA       NA
```

The default (what we did before) will return an `NA` median for every row within +/- 4 rows (`k-1`) of the previous `#VALUE!`; we can add `na.rm=TRUE` if you would prefer; that is not a rolling-window thing, that's a general-statistics question, "are empty values an issue".

Comment: Thanks, @r2evans for the answer. Actually, I do not want to do a rolling average like the answer you got at the start with basic operation. Rather, I want to do an average of 5 rows and then the average of the next 5 rows. How can I modify the code to give me that?

Comment: Yes, I misunderstood that. You need to clarify your question. BTW, I often find tumbling windows (that's what it's called) are usually "aligned" with something, such as 1Hz on 5Hz data, or weekly on weekday data, etc. Occasionally a tumbling window in the absence of "time" or another variable is certainly useful, but is there any "time" component in your data?

Comment: No, my data has no "time." But thank you anyways. You helped me understand many other things while answering the main question. Much appreciated.